# Get JSON object from URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get the value of the first 'price' field at the url:

http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singleorderdata&marketid=132

I am currently using the following code to do so:

```
getJSON('http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php? 
method=singleorderdata&marketid=132').then(function(data) {
var final = (data.return.DOGE.sellorders.price * totalcost) * 0.985
var finished = final.toFixed(8)
```

I have a strong feeling that I have done this bit wrong:

> data.return.DOGE.sellorders.price

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.return.DOGE.sellorders[0].price` because sellorders is an array

```js
$.getJSON('http://jsbin.com/pudoki/1.json', function(data){
  alert(data.return.DOGE.sellorders[0].price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```